# How do I install PyPy on appveyor?

Tags: pypy, appveyor

I have a Python extension that needs to be compiled against the PyPy interpreter on the Windows-based Appveyor continuous integration service. How do I get PyPy in that environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this PowerShell commands to "Install" phase of your build:

```
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-2.4.0-win32.zip', "$env:appveyor_build_folder\pypy3-2.4.0-win32.zip")
7z x pypy3-2.4.0-win32.zip | Out-Null
$env:path = "$env:appveyor_build_folder\pypy3-2.4.0-win32;$env:path"
```

Then you can call `pypy.exe` from anywhere in your build.